# How to highlight an Excel row when there is a string value in a cell on a row using Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to highlight a row in a spreadsheet (generated from my split_values dataframe) when there is a value in the cell under the "New Record ID" column  The absolute reference for the row is 'J'.

Below is my most recent attempt at doing this:

```
# Group entries by client name and create team spreadsheet

split_values = submitted_and_revised['Client Name'].unique()
print(split_values)

for value in split_values:
    teams = submitted_and_revised[submitted_and_revised['Client Name'] == value]
    output_file_name = "Team_" + str(value) + ".xlsx"

    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl.styles import numbers, PatternFill, colors
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
    from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
    from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
    from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
    from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle

    workbook = Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active

############################################################
    # This section works in this location, but I can't figure out how to make it conditional on the New Record ID in rule.formula .  I'm also not sure what the sheet.conditional_formating.add("A1:0100", rule) means...

    red_background = PatternFill(bgColor=colors.RED)
    diff_style = DifferentialStyle(fill=red_background)
    rule = Rule(type="expression", dxf=diff_style)
    rule.formula = ["$J1==working_revised['New Record ID']"]
    sheet.conditional_formatting.add("A1:O100", rule)

############################################################    


    #Format Column Widths
    #sheet.column_dimensions['C'].auto_size = True
    sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = float(18)
    sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = float(5)
    sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = float(25.25)
    sheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = float(20)
    sheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = float(6)
    sheet.column_dimensions['G'].width = float(65)
    sheet.column_dimensions['H'].width = float(20)
    sheet.column_dimensions['I'].width = float(14)
    sheet.column_dimensions['J'].width = float(14)
    sheet.column_dimensions['K'].width = float(50)


    for row in dataframe_to_rows(teams, index=False, header=True):
        sheet.append(row)
        for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=None):
            for cell in rows:
                cell.alignment = Alignment(vertical='center',wrapText=True)


    workbook.save(output_file_name)
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

---

Thank you Dror Av. for all the support you offered on this question.  I wasn't able to get your answer to work.  I'm still extremely new to coding in general, and I'm sure I was missing something simple.  I played with the code and finally came upon the below solution.

It doesn't work perfectly because in addition to the "New Record ID" rows that are highlighted, it also highlights the header row.  Despite trying to fix that piece, I haven't been able to.  For what it's worth, here is the solution I came up with:

```
# Import needed modules
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill, colors, Alignment
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

#Group by unique clients
split_values = submitted_and_revised['Client Name'].unique()
print(split_values)

for value in split_values:
    teams = submitted_and_revised[submitted_and_revised['Client Name'] == value]
    output_file_name = "Team_" + str(value) + ".xlsx"

    workbook = Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active

    #Format Column Widths
    #sheet.column_dimensions['C'].auto_size = True
    sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = float(3)
    sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = float(18)
    sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = float(25)
    sheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = float(20)
    sheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = float(10)
    sheet.column_dimensions['G'].width = float(50)
    sheet.column_dimensions['H'].width = float(15)
    sheet.column_dimensions['I'].width = float(32)
    sheet.column_dimensions['J'].width = float(25)
    sheet.column_dimensions['K'].width = float(50)

    red_background = PatternFill(bgColor=colors.RED)
    diff_style = DifferentialStyle(fill=red_background)
    rule = Rule(type="expression", dxf=diff_style)
    rule.formula = ["NOT(ISBLANK($J1))"]
    sheet.conditional_formatting.add("A1:Y100", rule)


    for row in dataframe_to_rows(teams, index=False, header=True):
        sheet.append(row)

    for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=None):
        for cell in rows:
            cell.alignment = Alignment(vertical='center', wrapText=True)



    workbook.save(output_file_name)
```

Comment: Your new formula just checks if cell `J1` has a value in it.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't import in a loop, or you will have a bad day. Imports go on the top of your code, see the [PEP8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) for more info on that and other guidelines on styling Python code.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, PatternFill, colors
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule

split_values = submitted_and_revised['Client Name'].unique()
print(split_values)

workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

for value in split_values:
    teams = submitted_and_revised[submitted_and_revised['Client Name'] == value]
    output_file_name = "Team_" + str(value) + ".xlsx"
```

Second, you do not have to create the rule on your own as you are using a simple [FormulaRule](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html#standard-conditional-formats). Now you just need to apply the rule to all the cell in the row:

```
for row in dataframe_to_rows(teams, index=False, header=True):
    sheet.append(row)

for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=None):
     for cell in rows:
        cell.alignment = Alignment(vertical='center', wrapText=True)
        sheet.conditional_formatting.add(f'{cell.coordinate}',
                                            FormulaRule(formula=["=NOT(ISBLANK(J{cell.row}))"],
                                                        fill=red_background))
```

At the end it should look like this, and when The cell `J{row}` is equal to `working_revised['New Record ID']` that specific row will have a red background. Do note that you are creating a new worbook with each teration of the loop, if that isn't your intention move:

```
workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
```

out of the loop.

Final code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, PatternFill, colors
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule


split_values = submitted_and_revised['Client Name'].unique()
print(split_values)

red_background = PatternFill(bgColor=colors.RED)

for value in split_values:
    teams = submitted_and_revised[submitted_and_revised['Client Name'] == value]
    output_file_name = "Team_" + str(value) + ".xlsx"

    workbook = Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active

    #Format Column Widths
    #sheet.column_dimensions['C'].auto_size = True
    sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = float(18)
    sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = float(5)
    sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = float(25.25)
    sheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = float(20)
    sheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = float(6)
    sheet.column_dimensions['G'].width = float(65)
    sheet.column_dimensions['H'].width = float(20)
    sheet.column_dimensions['I'].width = float(14)
    sheet.column_dimensions['J'].width = float(14)
    sheet.column_dimensions['K'].width = float(50)

    for row in dataframe_to_rows(teams, index=False, header=True):
        sheet.append(row)

    for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=None):
        for cell in rows:
            cell.alignment = Alignment(vertical='center', wrapText=True)
            sheet.conditional_formatting.add(f'{cell.coordinate}',
                                             FormulaRule(formula=["=NOT(ISBLANK(J{cell.row}))"],
                                                         fill=red_background))

    workbook.save(output_file_name)
```

Output should look something like this (ignore the random values):
[image: Excel Output]

Comment: Unfortunately, I got this error:  NameError: name 'FormulaRule' is not defined

Comment: I learned that I should add : from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule .  The problem is that now when I try to open the resulting excel file a window pops up saying "We found a problem with some content in 'Team_HPOT.xlsx'.  Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can... "  I said 'yes' and it brought up the file without any formatting.

Comment: @MercuryThrives I've edited it a bit, your last loop was **inside** the loop before, was that on purpose? it seemed like a wrong indent. It should work now. Is the value youre looking for in J cells == `working_revised['New Record ID']` or just `working_revised`?

Comment: @MercuryThrives I have found the culprit, in the formula you used `==` insted of just `=`. should be `"$J{cell.row}=\"working_revised['New Record ID']\""` and not `"$J{cell.row}==\"working_revised['New Record ID']\""`

Comment: Hi Dror Av, Thanks for hanging in there.  The output now produces an excel sheet, but the highlighting is still not occurring.  Does it make a difference that the cells in the working_revised dataframe "New Record ID" column are a concatination of a number of cells?  If it helps, here is an example of the value in one of the "New Record ID' cells:   hpotjohnsmithsupervisor2020-05-012020-05-09

Comment: @MercuryThrives, wait, when do you want to highlight the row? when there is any input in cell J or a specific one?

Comment: The sheet is being produced from a dataframe.  Some of the rows in that dataframe already have a "New Record ID".  I just want to output the dataframe to excel and add various formatting options.  One of which is highlighting any rows that have a "New Record ID".  Hope that clarifies.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MercuryThrives if I understood you correctly just switch the formula from `f"$J{cell.row}=\"working_revised['New Record ID']\"` to `f"=NOT(ISBLANK(J{cell.row}))"` that will highlight all rows that have a value in cell `J` of that row.